# Issue running advertools crawler

Tags: python

I'm relative newbie to python. I've been using advertools  however I've run into the following error

```
import advertools as adv
adv.crawl('https://sandpipercomms.com', 'my_output_file.jl', follow_links=True)
import pandas as pd
crawl_df = pd.read_json('my_output_file.jl', lines=True)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\tom\mu_code\vampire.py", line 2, in <module>
    adv.crawl('https://sandpipercomms.com', 'my_output_file.jl', follow_links=True)
  File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\python\mu\mu_venv-38-20220808-225806\lib\site-packages\advertools\spider.py", line 971, in crawl
    subprocess.run(command)
  File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Mu Editor\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 493, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Mu Editor\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Mu Editor\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 1311, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I'm currently running windows 10, python 3 and recently installed julia.
Any suggestions on what the issue might be would be appreciated.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct, and there may be issues in the setup of your machine.

As a quick solution, you can run the same code from this notebook, and you can do all the following work there:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1fXLx9dIBVBB5Due6VjDV947bsc7hii5x

Do you know how to setup a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)? This might help isolate the issue, and provide some insight, to understand the problem and come up with a solution.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Elias, 
Thanks for the link to the notebook. 
Yes I think its an issue with my machine will look to setup a virtual env and try get to the bottom of it. 
Cheers